# V15: Barcode App Error | You are expected to scan one or more products or a package available at the picking location

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, barcode, odoo-15

We have Products which we are buying in Pack and selling in Pack. for e.g. Pack of 6, Pack of 12.

Now product has 1 barcode and each packaging has different barcodes which I have added on product master packaging lines. Now I created a purchase order and receiving 60 Units in Pack of 6, so it equal to 10 Packaging Quantity.

I have confirmed the purchase order and now jump to barcode app to Scan Product Packaging Barcode. It must add 6 units every time but it is giving me this error. You are expected to scan one or more products or a package available at the picking location.

It is working fine when I am scanning barcode of product which add 1 Unit which I don't want in this case.

Please help me in this regards.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a functional one with no relation to any programming. Please ask such questions on [Odoo help forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Comment: Why are you voting to close this issue?? I already asked on Odoo help forum and no one is answering. It is not functional issue. We solved it by fixing bug of Odoo v15 Enterprise.

Comment: Then try to add more information to your question. Don't expect people to answer this question without giving even a traceback. And i would advise to open an issue on the official odoo github repository if you think that it is a bug. Or if it is an enterprise app (stock_barcode) then open an enterprise ticket.